# Python 3.6 | PyQt5 | QLabel doesn't display QPixmap

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qlabel

I'm trying to display a PNG image in a Widget using QLabel. I built the Widget using Qt Designer and the label shows the image properly. When I load the .ui into mi .py and execute it, everything shows up well, except for the label. I tried loading the QPixmap manually on the python code, but it didn't work either.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QPixmap)
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys
import os

form = uic.loadUiType('gui/Files/Login.ui')


class LoginWindow(form[0], form[1]):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.logoLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'logo.png'))))
        self.logoLabel.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = LoginWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Any sugestions on how could I display the image other than with QLabel?

Comment: Are you sure that the path of the image is correct ?, I recommend you print the path, also it is not necessary to use the following instruction: `self.logoLabel.show()`

Comment: The loading of image files (for `QIcon`, `QPixMap`, etc.) is done by plug-ins (e.g. qjpeg.dll for JPEG). May be, the resp. plug-in is missing. Though I think png support should be built-in in Qt. I found [Qt Image Formats](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimageformats-index.html) concerning this.

Comment: A weird bug we one day faced was that we could load a thingy.jpg _with_ transparency. This annoyed me much because I was _sure_ that JPEG doesn't support transparency. Finally, it turned out that the thingy.jpg was actually a mis-named PNG file whereby the loader obviously trusted the magic code (inside the file) more than the wrong suffix and, thus, confused as...